# How to attache location data to Timeline card in Mirror Api using .Net

Tags: asp.net, location, google-mirror-api, google-glass

I have location data to push users Timeline using .Net. I create Location Item and assign it to Location field in TimeLine Item like following code. but it did not show any location map or  data in Timeline card.but it shows Navigation. I need to show Location Image on card.

```
MirrorService Service = new MirrorService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                                                          {
                                                              Authenticator = Utils.GetAuthenticatorFromState(state)
                                                          });
                TimelineItem timelineItem = new TimelineItem();
                timelineItem.Creator = new Contact()
                                           {
                                               Id = "MEETUP_LOC",
                                               DisplayName = "Meetup Updates",
                                           };



                Location location = new Location() {};
                location.Address = "Voice Lounge, Colombo";
                location.Latitude = 6.887035;
                location.Longitude = 79.866193;

                timelineItem.Location = location;
                timelineItem.Notification = new NotificationConfig() {Level = "DEFAULT"};
                timelineItem.MenuItems = new List<MenuItem>()
                                             {
                                                 new MenuItem() {Action = "NAVIGATE"},
                                                 new MenuItem() {Action = "DELETE"},
                                                 new MenuItem() {Action = "SHARE"},
                                             };

                Service.Timeline.Insert(timelineItem).Fetch();
```

How I send location data with Map image. Should I use Html?.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the way to attaching location information. We can use html content to show the location data as an image like following code.

```
TimelineItem timelineItem = new TimelineItem();
                timelineItem.Creator = new Contact()
                                           {
                                               Id = "MEETUP_LOC",
                                               DisplayName = "Meetup Updates",
                                           };



                Location location = new Location() {};
                location.DisplayName = "Voice Lounge";
                location.Address = "Voice Lounge, Colombo";
                location.Latitude = 6.887035;
                location.Longitude = 79.866193;


                timelineItem.Html="<article>" +
                                  "<figure>" +
                                  "<img src=\"glass://map?w=240&h=360&marker=0;" +
                                   location.Latitude +
                                  "," +
                                   location.Longitude +
                                   "\"height=\"360\" width=\"240\">" +
                                  "</figure>" +
                                  "<section>" +
                                  "<div class=\"text-auto-size\"><p class=\"yellow\">" +
                                    location.DisplayName +
                                  "</p><p>" +
                                    location.Address +
                                  "</p>" +
                                  "</div>" +
                                  "</section>" +
                                  "</article>";
                timelineItem.Location = location;
                timelineItem.Notification = new NotificationConfig() {Level = "DEFAULT"};
                timelineItem.MenuItems = new List<MenuItem>()
                                             {
                                                 new MenuItem() {Action = "NAVIGATE"},
                                                 new MenuItem() {Action = "DELETE"},
                                                 new MenuItem() {Action = "SHARE"},
                                             };

                Service.Timeline.Insert(timelineItem).Fetch();
```